# HttpClient POST long delay before request processing on IIS, multithreading

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, iis-7.5, dotnet-httpclient

I have a simple console application which sends HTTP POST from multiple threads:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SendQuery(url1, query1)));
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SendQuery(url2, query2)));
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

`SendQuery(string uri, string requestString)` looks like this:

```
Uri url = new Uri(uri);

try
{
   using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient { Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0) })
   {
      StringContent content = new StringContent(requestString);
      content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
      HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
      response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
   }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

The program works without any errors, all the queries are processed finally, but after filling `tasks` list each thread hangs on `client.PostAsync(url, content).Result`, after **several minutes** IIS starts to process queries. Why does this delay occur? What's happening during this time? I am using IIS 7.5 running on Windows Server 2008 R2 to host web-services which provide `url1` and `url2`.

Comment: Pass a single instance of HttpClient into your SendQuery method or make the HttpClient instance a field.  Reusing the HttpClient instance is more efficient.

Comment: It would also be much more efficient if you made the SendQuery method async instead of creating a whole new thread for every request.

Answer (score 0):

Set this value to 500 or 1000 at the start of your program and let us know the effects.
Your requests maybe getting throttled at the default value of 2. (depending on the .net version)

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 500;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help. Maybe I should add some specific settings to services or IIS configuration? The services are implemented as WCF services.

Comment: @QuéPadre. Try the opposite,  set the DefaultConnectionLimit = 2.  My testing has shown that HttpClient ignores the DefaultConnectionLimit unless you explicitly set it.  By hitting the server with 200 requests simultaneously, you spend a lot of time setting up 200 connections before any real work gets done.